# pandas: Convert string column to ordered Category?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with pandas for the first time. I have a column with survey responses in, which can take 'strongly agree', 'agree', 'disagree', 'strongly disagree', and 'neither' values.

This is the output of `describe()` and `value_counts()` for the column:

```
count      4996
unique        5
top       Agree
freq       1745
dtype: object
Agree                1745
Strongly agree        926
Strongly disagree     918
Disagree              793
Neither               614
dtype: int64
```

I want to do a linear regression on this question versus overall score. However, I have a feeling that I should convert the column into a Category variable first, given that it's inherently ordered. Is this correct? If so, how should I do this?

I've tried this:

```
df.EasyToUseQuestionFactor = pd.Categorical.from_array(df.EasyToUseQuestion)
print df.EasyToUseQuestionFactor
```

This produces output that looks vaguely right, but it seems that the categories are in the wrong order. Is there a way that I can specify ordering? Do I even need to specify ordering?

This is the rest of my code right now:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./data/responses.csv')
lm1 = ols('OverallScore ~ EasyToUseQuestion', data).fit()
print lm1.rsquared
```

Comment: See here for upcoming full categorical support (this is going to be in 0.15.0, not released yet): http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/categorical.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you should convert it to categorical data and this should do the trick

```
likert_scale = {'strongly agree':2, 'agree':1, 'neither':0, 'disagree':-1, 'strongly disagree':-2}
df['categorical_data'] = df.EasyToUseQuestion.apply(lambda x: likert_scale[x])
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to use `.map` rather than `.apply` but otherwise this worked.

Answer (score 15):

Two ways to do it nowadays. Your column would be more readable and use less memory. Since it will be a Categorical Type you still will be able to order the values.

First my preferred one:

```
df['grades'].astype('category')
```

`astype` used to accept a `categories` argument, but it isn't [present anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952128/pandas-astype-categories-not-working). So if:

- you want to order your categories in a not lexicographical order,
- or to have extra categories that aren't present in your data,
  you must use the solution below.

This recommendation is from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#controlling-behavior)

```
In [26]: from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
In [27]: s = pd.Series(["a", "b", "c", "a"])
In [28]: cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=["b", "c", "d"],
   ....:                             ordered=True)
In [29]: s_cat = s.astype(cat_type)
```

Extra tip to create extra values: get all existing values from a column with `df.column_name.unique()` and add your non present column names.

Comment: `.astype()` now errors if you pass `'categories'`. The method now figures out the categories automatically.

Comment: @jeffhale what should I do if some categories aren't present in the data?

Comment: Your second example - the one from the docs - works fine with categories that aren't present in the data.

Answer (score 1):

[`pandas.factorize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) can obtain a numeric representation of an array.

*factorize* is available as both a top-level function [`pandas.factorize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html#pandas.factorize), and as a method [`Series.factorize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html#pandas.Series.factorize)and [`Index.factorize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.factorize.html#pandas.Index.factorize)

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'answer' : ['strongly agree', 'strongly agree', 'agree', 'neither', 'disagree', 'strongly disagree']})

# df['category'] = pd.factorize(df['answer'])[0]
df['category'] = df['answer'].factorize()[0]
```

```
# print(df)

              answer  category
0     strongly agree            0
1     strongly agree            0
2              agree            1
3            neither            2
4           disagree            3
5  strongly disagree            4
```