# pandas astype categories not working

Tags: pandas

I tired to change column to `catgeory` using documentation from http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5], 'B':['a','b','c','d','e'], 'C':['A','B','A','B','A']})
df['C']=df['C'].astype('category')
```

If I try to pass the categories

```
df['C']=df['C'].astype('category',categories=['A','B'])
```

It errors out saying

```
TypeError: _astype() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categories'
```

whats the right way to pass categories to `astype()`?

Comment: I get the same error you do if I run both `df['C']=df['C'].astype('category')` and `df['C']=df['C'].astype('category',categories=['A','B'])`.  However, I don't get any errors if I just run `df['C']=df['C'].astype('category',categories=['A','B'])` after initializing the DataFrame.

Comment: I don't see error in both the statements.

Comment: @root, what is your pandas and numpy versions?

Comment: @MaxU: pandas 0.18.1 and numpy 1.11.0

Comment: i guess it's a numpy v. 1.10.4, which doesn't know this argument...

Comment: @shivsn:  Neither statement by itself gives me an error.  I only get an error if I run all three lines of code in the question consecutively.  If I only run lines 1 and 2, or only lines 1 and 3, no errors.

Comment: On my machine,  1 ,2 ; 1,3; and  1 ,3 ,2; seems like cant use  'categories' on column that is already a type --  category. numpy 1.11

Comment: @MaxU i am using numpy 1.10.4 on mac. Anything different on mac which doesnt work?

Comment: Updated numpy to latest version, now 3 works.

Answer (score 9):

You now need to now pass it in via CategorialDtype as the `astype` method no longer accepts them

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5], 'B':['a','b','c','d','e'], 'C':['A','B','A','B','A']})
df['C']=df['C'].astype(CategoricalDtype(categories=['A','B']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Categorical works too.

```
myCategory = ['A','B']
df['C'] = pd.Categorical(df['C'], categories=myCategory, ordered=True)
```